# What does univoque mean?

Tags: soft-question

This seems to be a french word that is used in English language mathematical papers.  It seems to mean something like "unambiguous."  What is its technical definition?

Comment: biunivoque is just French for bijective, as far as I know; I don't recall seeing it in English language papers. What example did you have in mind?

Comment: Caution: I've also seen "biunivoque" used for just "injective" (for example, Grothendieck's _Produits tensoriels topologiques et espaces nucleaires_). I've also seen "biunivocal" in English (Schaefer's _Topological vector spaces_, again used for "injective").

Comment: @Andrew: I've also seen univoque used for partial functions; same difference but in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 3):

Univoque means single-valued, as opposed to multi-valued (multivoque). As Yemon Choi explained, biunivoque means bijective (i.e. single-valued both ways).

Comment: A French English dictionary gives 'univocal' as a translation. I presume the idea is 'with one voice' therefore as suggested 'unambiguous'. The specification of a function is in no two minds as to what image $f(x)$ to assign to $x$. That is a neat image. Thanks for the question.


Answer (score 1):

So a univoque map is just a function, as opposed to a multivoque map, a relation.